# при отправке запроса в базу данных не находит нужный результат

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

пытаюсь реализовать алфавитный указатель с русскими буквами для поиска книги (с английскими всё работает хорошо). Отправляю в бд такой запрос[image]
где letter - это буква с которой должно начинаться название книги.
 Этот параметр передается из реквеста в таком виде: 
[http://localhost:8080/Library_8/pages/books.jsp?letter=Б](http://localhost:8080/Library_8/pages/books.jsp?letter=%D0%91)

Но он ничего не находит, хотя в базе точно есть названия которые начинаются с "Б"

[image: попытка найти в базе все книги начинающиеся на Б]

если выполнять sql запрос из базы то всё находится нормально.

Кодировки базы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инструменты разработчика chrome:
с англ буквой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с русской (почему так?)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать)

UPD(1):
запрос который идет в бд (из логов сервера ),в него я ещё добавил конвертирование char set в utf8mb4:

> Info:    select b.id,b.name,b.isbn,b.page_count,b.publish_year, p.name as publisher, a.fio as author, g.name as genre, b.image from book b inner join author a on b.author_id=a.id inner join genre g on b.genre_id=g.id inner join publisher p on b.publisher_id=p.id where substr(b.name,1,1)=convert('Б', char character set utf8mb4) order by b.name limit 0,5

Опять таки если писать в воркбенче то всё работает.

hex литерал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

hex поле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видно, второе значение поля начинается с тех же символов что и  код буквы Б

Comment: Для начала, я бы проверил какой SQL запрос фактически формируеться перед тем как он уйдет на бд, мало ли какие погрешности есть в данных. На первый взгляд сам запрос выглядит ок, но мало ли. Во вторых явно стоит обратить внимание на то что происходит в getBooks, тк он не выглядит как стандартный метод для выполнения sql запроса.

Comment: *Но он ничего не находит, хотя в базе точно есть названия которые начинаются с "Б"* Обычно charset/collation подставляемого в запрос строкового литерала не имеет ничего общего с charset/collation поля, по которому выполняется поиск. В данном случае строковый литерал скорее всего будет latin1, так что сравнение с utf8mb4-значением поля ожидаемо ничего не даст. Можете это проверить выводом HEX() от литерала и от поля. Используйте явное приведение charset строкового литерала в тексте запроса функцией CONVERT. И следите за coercibility.